# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I've been working in a script to run some network connectivity checks to remote devices, and all the functions seems to be working when I run it locally on my machine.

But as soon as I've added the Invoke-Command to my script it connects to the server finely, but then all the variables from my functions are getting 'null' values.

I'm using global variables to get out of the scope of my functions so I can interact with them as I wasn't able to return them other way.

This is the part of the code that fails:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Machines[$j] -Credential $credentials
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

    $OSVersions = (Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Machines[$j]).caption
    Network-Info -Machine $Machines[$j] -OSVersion $OSVersions -Techinfo $TechInfoNew

}
Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 1 -Title $Machines[$j] -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i #fix the counter var
Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 2 -Title $OSVersions -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i

foreach($result in $global:results){

    Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 3 -Title $global:Tech[$k] -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i
    Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 4 -Title $result -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i
    $k++
    $i++

}
```

The errors are thrown in the foreach statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can see you are specting the `Invoke-Command` to run one of the functions in your script, and that can be done, what can't be done though is for the scriptblock in the 
`Invoke-Command` to see the variables you have defined in you script, you also need to modify the function to return values instead of modifying global variables.

Try this:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Machines[$j] -Credential $credentials
$results = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [String]$host,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [String]$OSVersions,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [String]$TechInfoNew
    )
    $OSVersions = (Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $host).caption
    return Network-Info -Machine $host -OSVersion $OSVersions -Techinfo $TechInfoNew

} -ArgumentList $Machines[$j], $OSVersions, $TechInfoNew
Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 1 -Title $Machines[$j] -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i #fix the counter var
Export-Excel $FullPath -WorksheetName "Results" -StartColumn 2 -Title $OSVersions -TitleSize 12 -StartRow $i

foreach($result in $results){
    #Should have values now.
}
```

`return` keyword is not necessary but recommended to make it easier to read, I also see the that inside your foreach you use another global variable, if this was also modified by the function you need to also return it, to return multiple values create a `PSCustomObject`, like this

```
.
. code
.
$customObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    prop1 = value1;
    prop2 = value2;
    prop3 = value3;
}
return $customObject
```

Hope it helps, good luck.